# How does a liferay portal work?

Tags: liferay, portal

I am developing a portal page using the Liferay . I want to know the technical aspects of it. What exactly happens in the background when a portlet (either a custom built or an inbuilt) is dragged and dropped to the portal page. Curious to know. Please give me some insights.

Thanks

Comment: Mention the version of the Liferay that you are planning to use. Liferay Documentation has a detailed explanation and you could also refer to this site http://www.liferaysavvy.com/ this has some good basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to go through some basic portlet documentation first before start up here. Liferay itself is having nice documentation for developers, which you might want to checkout.

[LIFERAY DEVELOPER DOCUMENTATION](https://dev.liferay.com//develop)

Comment: Ok.. but does that documentation talk about the background happening?

Comment: Nope. Its not that much of descriptive. If you are really interested in background stuff, you have to read portlet specification or "portlet in action" book.